# Can anyone help with the inverse problem and tuning parameters

Tags: parameter-estimation, inverse-problems, logistic-regression

[image: this picture summarises the model, the parameters and the data of the population of london from 1985 to 2015]For my final year project i want to model the population of London using the Verhulst logistic model. However, to gain more marks i wish to use the inverse problem to tune the parameters to make the model match the real live values better. The problem is i have limited resources on the inverse problem and hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thankyou.

Also, if someone can recommend a better population model i would highly appreciate that aswell.

Comment: I do not see what you mean by the inverse problem. What is measured is population; so this is what you need to fit. Could you clarify ?

Comment: My supervisor advised me to do this which is why i think i am also unclear myself so i apologise for not being greatly specific. my understanding of it is i need to tune the parameters in order to make my model more accurate to the population of london. he said i can do this using the inverse problem. i think parameter estimation is just a branch within inverse problems in order to minimise errors between my model values and the actual population of london in order to make my model more accurate. i hope this clears it up for you

Comment: This is a parameter estimation question and clearly an inverse problem. Could you write down your equation, and in particular what the unknown parameters are, and a little bit about the data you have? You can edit the question by pressing the "edit" button there or via https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3179480/edit

Comment: i have added a picture which i hope clarifies my work to you

Comment: I think you should read about inverse problems and see if this fits what you want to do. Right now I think your question revolves more around parameter estimation than anything else. Try to clarify your question and show things that you have tried.